# Can't find column names when using group by function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
   Country    City        POI       Type
0   NL       Amsterdam    KFC       restaurant
1   NL       Amsterdam    KFC       cafe
2   NL       Arnhem     McDonalds   fast food
3   NL       Arnhem     McDonalds   ice cream
```

I need to group by type column so I do not have duplicates in all other columns. In other words, I need an output like this:

```
   Country    City        POI       Type
0   NL       Amsterdam    KFC       restaurant, cafe
1   NL       Arnhem     McDonalds   fast food, ice cream
```

I tried to use group by function, but  all column names disappear, and shape function shows 0 columns. Maybe there is a better way to group those values?

Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array([['','Country','City', 'POI', 'Type'],
            [0,"NL","Amsterdam", 'KFC', 'cafe'],
            [1,"NL","Amsterdam", 'KFC', 'restaurant'],
            [2,"NL","Arnhem", 'McDonalds', 'fast-food'],
            [3,"NL","Arnhem", 'McDonalds', 'ice cream']]
           )

initial_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:])

final_df = initial_df .groupby( [ "Country", "City", "POI", "Type"] ).count()

print(list(final_df.columns.values))
print(final_df.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group to `str.join`:

```
res = df.groupby(['Country', 'City', 'POI'])['Type'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()

print(res)

  Country       City        POI                Type
0      NL  Amsterdam        KFC    restaurant, cafe
1      NL     Arnhem  McDonalds  fastfood, icecream
```

Comment: Thanks jpp, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `final_df` is empty because you asked `pandas` to group by all of your columns. 
If you only want to group by the columns `"Type"` here is what you should do:

```
grouped = initial_df .groupby( ["Type"] )
```

You then applied the `count()` function to the grouped dataframe. This will count the instances of non `nan` elelemnts in each column for each of your groups.
What you want to do though is access each group.
You can do that by doing so:

```
for name, group in grouped:
   print(name) # this prints the Type of your group
   print(group) # this prints the dataframe corrisponging to your Type
```

Hope this helped.